# Counting occurences of number in a list separated by spaces using dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

If I have a list of numbers (ex:- `1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 4 5 3` ) how can I use dictionaries in python to count the occurrences of each number in the list?
So the output be something like:

Enter numbers separated by spaces :`1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 4 5 3`

```
{'1': 2, '3': 4, '2': 4, '5': 1, '4': 1}

1 occurs 2 times

3 occurs 4 times

2 occurs 4 times

5 occurs one time

4 occurs one time
```

Also if a number occurs only once the output should be  "one time".

This is what I have so far:

```
numbers=input("Enter numbers separated by spaces:-")
count={}
for number in numbers:
    if number in count:
        count[number] = count[number]+1
    else:
        count[number] = 1

print(number)
```

but my output ends up being the last number, i, input can someone help me?

OK, this is what I have now:

```
numbers = input("Enter numbers separated by spaces:-") # i.e. '1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 4 5 3'
my_list = list(map(int, numbers.strip().split(' ')))
count = {}
for x in set(my_list):
   count[x] = my_list.count(x)
print(count)
for key, value in count.items():
    if value == 1:
         print('{} occurs one time'.format(key))
    else:
         print('{} occurs {} times'.format(key, value))
```

This is what I have now and it seems pretty good, if theres any way to make it better please do let me know. Thanks a lot everybody

Comment: counter is not defined is what i get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set()` method returns a list of unique values in an iterable, and the `count()` method returns the number of occurrences of a particular number a list.

Using these facts, you can solve the problem by doing something like below.

```
numbers = input("Enter numbers seperated by spaces:-") # i.e. '1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 4 5 3'
my_list = list(map(int, numbers.strip().split(' ')))
count = {}
for x in set(my_list):
    count[x] = my_list.count(x)

for key, value in count.items():
    if value == 1:
        print('{} occurs one time'.format(key))
    else:
        print('{} occurs {} times'.format(key, value))
```

Comment: ive tried this but this is what i get                                        builtins.AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing you are using Python 3.x. Try: `my_list = list(map(int, numbers.split(' ')))`

Comment: i get no output, nothin happens

Comment: Did you `print(count)` in the end? Also, try to add the `.strip()` method to the numbers string (see my updated answer). This will remove any leading or trailing whitespace. I just ran this code, and it works as expected.

Comment: this is alot more complicated then i thought

Comment: how can i get a list of it occuerence ex:-{'1': 2, '3': 4, '2': 4, '5': 1, '4': 1}

Comment: Do as I told you - `print(count)` in the end of the script.

Comment: would this program  be considered using dictionaries, i just want to make sure cause it looks kinda of different from what i expected of a python program that includes dictionary

Comment: Yes, it would be considered as a program that uses dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

You're close -- you want `print(count)`, not `print(number)` so that you're printing the dictionary.

Incidentally, you can use the `Counter` class from the `collections` library to do this for you:

```
>>> import collections
>>> numbers = input("Enter numbers ").split(' ')
>>> count = Counter(numbers)
>>> print(count)
```

Comment: also how can i get the output as i have displayed in my question

Answer (score 1):

Try counters:

```
>>> import collections
>>> number_string = '1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 4 5 3'
>>> number_list = number_string.split(' ') # provide a list split on the spaces
>>> counts = collections.Counter(number_list)
>>> counts
Counter({'2': 4, '3': 4, '1': 2, '4': 1, '5': 1})
```

You can also count as you go:

```
>>> counts = collections.Counter()
>>> for l in "GATTACA":
...     counts[l] +=1
... 
>>> counts
Counter({'A': 3, 'T': 2, 'C': 1, 'G': 1})
```

To print this nicely:

```
import collections

def print_counts_in_spaced_string(number_string):
    number_list = number_string.split(' ') # provide a list split on the spaces
    counts = collections.Counter(number_list)
    for key, value in counts.items():
        format_string = '{key} occurs {value} {times}'
        if value == 1:
            value, times = 'one', 'time'
        else:
            times = 'times'
        print(format_string.format(key=key, value=value, times=times))

number_string = '1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 4 5 3'
print_counts_in_spaced_string(number_string)
```

Which prints:

```
1 occurs 2 times
2 occurs 4 times
3 occurs 4 times
4 occurs one time
5 occurs one time
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you start off with an empty `dict`. This means that your check `if number in count` will always fail (since `count` is an empty dictionary).

I would recommend using [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html) as others have suggested. But if you're really looking to debug your code, then here's what I would do:

```
numbers=input("Enter numbers seperated by spaces:-")
count={}
for number in numbers.split(): # ignore all the white-spaces
  if number not in count:
    count[number] = 0
  count[number] += 1
for num,freq in count.items():
  print(num, "occurs", freq, "times")
```

Comment: using this code my output ends up being a repeated  cycle                 example input was 1 2 3 2                                                 output was :-1 occurs 1 times
2 occurs 1 times
1 occurs 1 times
2 occurs 1 times
3 occurs 1 times
1 occurs 1 times
2 occurs 2 times
3 occurs 1 times
1 occurs 1 times

Comment: @user2994135: sorry about that - I got mixed up with the code indentation and the formatting indentation. Fixed now!